# How to convert Collection<X> to Object[][] via lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is there a way to convert a Collection to an array of array of objects, populated with members of X via lambda expressions?

```
Object[{Collection.size}][{X.a},{X.b}]
```

What I'm in need of is

```
collection.stream()
          .filter(o->o.use())
          .<insert inner convertion to Object[] {o.getA(), o.getB()} here>
          .toArray()
```

Comment: `.map(o -> new Object[]{o.getA(), o.getB()})`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it yourself.

```
collection.stream()
          .filter(o->o.use())
          .map (o-> new Object[] {o.getA(), o.getB()})
          .toArray();
```